# Cannot set data from API response using useState in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have function that gets the data from API request. I want to put this data to the state variable, but for some kind of reason it doesn't work, when printing the state it always shows the empty array.

```
export default function Buttons({setOptionButtons, sendMessage, places}){

    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [names, setNames] = useState([])
    const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(data)
    }
    ,[data])

    const pressOption = (input, option) => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            for (const place of option){
                setLoading(true);
                try {
                    const requests = option.map((place) =>
                        axios.get(`url`)
                    );

                    const responses = await Promise.all(requests);
                    console.log(responses)
                    const items = responses.flatMap((response) => response.data.result.items);
                    const newNames = items.map((item) => item.name);
                    const newAddresses = items.map((item) => item.address_name);

                    setNames((prevNames) => [...prevNames, ...newNames]);
                    setAddresses((prevAddresses) => [...prevAddresses, ...newAddresses]);
                    setError(null);
                    console.log('Hello');
                    console.log(names)
                } catch(error) {
                    setError(error.message)
                } finally {
                    setLoading(false)
                }
            }
        };

        fetchData();
        setOptionButtons(false);
        sendMessage(input);
    }
    return (
///html code
    )
}
```

I tried to use promise.all and to call the printing outside the fetchData function. It should print data which I pass via useState.

Comment: Why do you send requests for each option in a for loop? If you have 10 options you will send 100 requests.

Comment: You forgot to encase the `process.env.TWO_GIS_KEY` in`${}` for it to be a valid template string.

Comment: @jcubic there can't be more than 3 options in my app. But I already told that it is better to do it with promise.all, thank you for reminder

Comment: Does newNames actually have the new names or is it an empty array also. (console.log)

Comment: @FabioNettis, thank you a lot, but it did not solved my problem

Comment: If you have 3 options you're sending 9 requests for no reason.

Comment: How od you use pressOption? Please show the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have taken the liberty of refactoring your code to the point where it should work, the issue I have discovered is that call to `Array.map` inside the for loop, this seems to bug out your state. You will find comments I have added across your function explaining why I have done what,

```
function Buttons({ setOptionButtons, sendMessage, places }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);
  const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([]);
  
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onClick = useCallback(async (input, option) => {
    // early return if the data is already fetching
    if (!!loading) return;
    setError(null);
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const promises = [];

      // more readable implementation of the for loop
      for (const place of option) {
        promises.push(axios.get("..."));
      }

      // Maybe use `Promise.allSettled` for better error handling
      const responses = await Promise.all(promises);

      const items = responses.flatMap((response) => {
        return response.data.result.items;
      });

      const newNames = items.map((item) => {
        return item.name;
      });

      const newAddresses = items.map((item) => {
        return item.address_name;
      });

      setNames((prev) => [...prev, ...newNames]);
      setAddresses((prev) => [...prev, ...newAddresses]);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    } finally {
      // handle all other updates directly inside the finally block
      setLoading(false);
      setOptionButtons(false);
      sendMessage(input);
    }
  }, [loading, sendMessage, setOptionButtons]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(data);
  }, [data]);

  return <></>;
}

export default Buttons;
```

Also you seem to be new to react, definitely take a look at the [official documentation](https://react.dev/learn) for react. They have just updated their entire documentation and it is really informative.

###### PS:

As the comments state above you will have pretty excessive requests to the API your calling, if you are paying per request or bandwidth I strongly recommend another refractor over that passage of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helped me! But I already solved it in different way, posted it down here.
Also, I reconsidered my for loop and replaced it with one Promise.all for making several calls.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was the line `setOptionButtons(false)`, which is asyncrhonous. So I added `await` to this line and shuffled it with `updateOptionButtons()`, so that it waits until first asynchronous function ends.

Also, it is better to use `Promise.all` to handle multiple requests to API as I did here instead of using for-loop.

```js
export default function Buttons({setOptionButtons, sendMessage, places}){

    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [error, setError] = useState(null)
    const [names, setNames] = useState([])
    const [addresses, setAddresses] = useState([])

    const updateOptionButtons = () => {
        setOptionButtons(false);
      };


    const pressOption = async (input, option) => {
        const urlArray = []

        for(let i = 0; i < option.length; i++){
            urlArray.push(urls_with_option[i])
        }

        let requestsArray = urlArray.map((url) => {
            let request = new Request(url);
            return request;
        });
     

        await Promise.all(requestsArray.map((request) => {
            return fetch(request).then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            }).then((data) => {
                return data;
            });
        })).then((values) => {
            let items = values[0].result.items;
            let names = items.map((item) => item.name);
            let addresses = items.map((item) => item.address_name);
            setData(values)
            setNames((prevNames)=> [...prevNames, ...names])
            setAddresses((prevAdaress)=> [...prevAdaress, ...addresses])
        }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
        
        await sendMessage(input);
        updateOptionButtons()
    }

    return (
      //Html code here
    )
}
```